# How to make my WHERE clause not run a syntax error in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

The questions asks,

"Write a query to display the customer name and the number of payments they have made where the amount on the check is greater than their average payment amount. Order the results by the descending number of payments."

So far I have,

```
 SELECT customerName, 
                (SELECT COUNT(checkNumber) FROM Payments WHERE 
                 Customers.customerNumber = Payments.customerNumber) AS
                 NumberOfPayments
FROM Customers
WHERE amount > SELECT AVG(amount)
ORDER BY NumberOfPayments DESC;
```

But I am getting a syntax error every-time I run out. What am I doing incorrectly in this situation?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen MY SQL Workbench Version 8.0.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax error comes from the fact that you are having an incorrect second subquery: `amount > SELECT AVG(amount)` doesn't work.

You could use `amount > (SELECT AVG(amount) FROM Payments)`.

That is: complete the subquery and put it between ( ).

However this won't do what you want (plus it is inefficient).

Now since this is not a forum to do your homework for you, I will leave it at this and thus only help you with the actual question: why do you get the syntax error. Keep on looking, you will find it. No better way to learn than to search and find yourself.

Comment: So when I wrote that the query wouldn’t work, I was incorrect? The query will actually do what he described?

Comment: Look at the subject. The wuestion was: why do I get an error. Not: do my homework. So that is EXACTLY what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase this as an inner join between the two tables, with a correlated subquery to find the average payment amount per customer:

```
SELECT
    c.customerName,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN p.amount > (SELECT AVG(p2.amount) FROM Payments p2
                                WHERE p2.customerName = c.customerName)
               THEN 1 END) AS NumberOfPayments
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Payments p
    ON c.customerNumber = p.customerNumber
GROUP BY
    c.customerNumber
ORDER BY
    NumberOfPayments DESC;
```

Your current query is on the right track, but you need to do something called conditional aggregation to obtain the count.  In this case, we aggregate by customer then assert that a given payment amount is greater than his average before we include it in the count.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this just using `JOIN`s:

```
SELECT c.customerName,
       SUM( p.amount > p2.avg_amount ) as Num_Payments_Larger_Than_Average 
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Payments p
     ON c.customerNumber = p.customerNumber LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT p2.customerNumber, AVG(amount) as avg_amount
      FROM payments p2
      GROUP BY p2.customerNumber
     ) p2
     ON p2.customerNumber = p.customerNumber
GROUP BY c.customerNumber, c.customerName
ORDER BY Num_Payments_Larger_Than_Average;
```

Some notes about this answer.  First, it uses `LEFT JOIN` and conditional aggregation.  This allows the query to return customers with zero payments larger than their average -- that is, customers with no payments or all of whose payments are the same.

Second, it includes `customerNumber` in the `GROUP BY`.  I think this is important, because it may be possible for two customers to have the same name.